# Execute function in external assembly loaded in different appdomain

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, .net-assembly, appdomain

### Task

- ***Load and/or unload external assembly at runtime.***
- ***Execute code in the external assembly, passing variables to the external code and expecting a return value.***

#### [Problem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173101.aspx)

> There is no way to unload an individual assembly without unloading all of the application domains that contain it. Use the Unload method from `AppDomain` to unload the application domains.

#### Solution

Create a new `AppDomain`, load the external assembly into the new `AppDomain` and execute whatever code you need to execute in the external assembly and (*optional*) destroy the new `AppDomain` afterwards.

#### Problem 2

Unfortunately this process is not trivial and requires that you use an *intermediary proxy* object that can invoke a method in a remote `AppDomain` without referencing the object in the local application domain in any way (which again would lock the assembly into the local `AppDomain`).

#### Solution 2

Creating an *assembly proxy* (or wrapper), derived from `MarshalByRefObject`, so that the `CLR` can marshal it by reference across `AppDomain` boundaries.

---

I found [**this**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/453778/Loading-Assemblies-from-Anywhere-into-a-New-AppDom) piece of code for doing exactly what I need to do, but...

Therefor I have now come to you **StackOverflow** to ask for help as I can't seem to figure out what is wrong, why and how to fix it.

*For now trust me on this, the loading of the external assembly in the new AppDomain is working fine, but the invocation of code in the external assembly is not.*

Here is some code I have for invoking the external assembly

```
public class SOAPWebServiceInvoker
{
    private readonly Guid _assemblyId;
    private readonly IAssemblyManager _assemblyManager;
    private readonly Foo _foo;

    public SOAPWebServiceInvoker(IAssemblyManager assemblyManager, Guid assemblyId, string url)
    {
        _assemblyManager = assemblyManager;
        _assemblyId = assemblyId;
        _foo = new Foo { Url = url };
    }

    public object Invoke(string className, string methodName, Dictionary<string, object> methodParameters)
    {
        return _assemblyManager.Reflect(_assemblyId, assembly => _foo.Invoke(assembly, className, methodName, methodParameters));
    }
}
```

Previously the code in `Foo` was located in the `SOAPWebServiceInvoker` class, but I got an exception saying: `Type 'SOAPWebServiceInvoker' in assembly '...' is not marked as serializable`, so I moved into a separate class just to see if that fixed the problem (because `Foo` should be `Serializable`).

```
[Serializable]
public class Foo
{
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public object Invoke(Assembly assembly, string className, string methodName, Dictionary<string, object> methodParameters)
    {
        var type = GetTypeInAssembly(assembly, Url, className);
        var method = GetMethodOfType(type, Url, className, methodName);
        var parameters = method.GetParameters();

        if (method.DeclaringType == null) throw new Exception("DecleringType was null for methodInfo.");

        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(method.DeclaringType);
        return method.Invoke(instance, methodParameters.Select(x =>
        {
            var parameterType = parameters.Single(y => y.Name.Equals(x.Key)).ParameterType;
            if (parameterType.IsEnum)
            {
                return Enum.Parse(parameterType, x.Value.ToString());
            }
            return Convert.ChangeType(x.Value, parameterType);
        }).ToArray());
    }

    private Type GetTypeInAssembly(Assembly assembly, string url, string className) {...}        
    private MethodInfo GetMethodOfType(Type type, string url, string className, string methodName) {...}
}
```

But I am still getting the serialization exception *(but for `Foo`):* `Type 'Foo' in assembly '...' is not marked as serializable`.

It may just be a stupid mistake that I have overlooked, but I cant for the life of me find out what it is and why this won't work... :S

Comment: I am not sure about the error you are seeing, but just a comment, if the data returned from external assembly is a class contained in the external assembly the external assembly will get loaded in both app domains when the main up domain attempts to deserialize the type.

Comment: Just to be sure: the real `Foo` class does not have any fields (except the backing field for `Url`)?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis The only thing I have left out of class `Foo` is the implementation of the two methods at the bottom.